# Array to read different values

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can I input multiple values in PowerShell and have those values stored in a variable?

For example:

```
$value = Read-Host "Enter the value's" #I need 15 values to be entered.
```

And then recall them e.g:

```
$value[0] = 1233
$value[1] = 2345
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you could declare an array `@()` and then use a loop and the addition operator to add items to the array (stopping when a blank value is submitted):

```
$values = @()

Do{
    $value = read-host "Enter a value"
    if ($value) {$values += $value}
}Until (-not $value)
```

You can then retrieve values as you described via the index with square brackets `[]`:

```
$values       #returns all values
$values[3]    #returns the fourth value (if you entered four or more)
```

Beware that arrays start from 0, so the first item is `[0]`, second is `[1]` etc. With PowerShell you can also use negative numbers to work through the array backwards, so `[-1]` is the last item, `[-2]` the second to last, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Stores the readin values in an array:

```bsh
$values = @()

$i = $null
while ($i -ne "q") {
    if ($i -ne $null) {
        # Attach value to array
        $values += $i
    }
    $i = Read-Host "Enter value (stop with q)"
}

# Print each value in a seperate line
$values | % { Write-Host $_}
# Print type -> to visualize that it is an array
$values.GetType()

# Several values can be retrieved via index operator
$values[0]
```